# How to create a very simple password protected page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a very simple password protected page for a page in Laravel - ideally I dont want to create a form etc. It doesn't need to be overly secure at this stage. Something like below, but where a user has to type in a password for a single route.

```
Route::get('your-route', function () {
   // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth.basic');
```

Comment: and what is not working with your code there?

Comment: What you have here should create a page at /your-route which requires basic authentication.  You just need to replace the comment with the content you want. As a next small step, replace "// Only authenticated users may enter..." with "return('Only authenticated users see this');

Comment: well i never had to enter a password to enter the site? that's what im after... a simple field that users have to type in a simple password before they get sent to that page.

Comment: any ideas how i create a simple password field they have to enter here? @mrhn

Comment: If you are using user authentication, you could restrict access with the user ID.

If not, you can ask for a password with some javascript when the link is clicked. Send password with a post request, return a response depending of that check. Create a random token and use it to give access on request. Delete token after it been used. Return error 400 for each request made without a token.